# Memory allocation for const in C#

Tags: c#

How is memory allocated when I use:

```
public class MyClass
{       
    public const string myEVENT = "Event";
    //Other code
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, it's a compile-time constant - so if you use it from other assemblies, "Event" will be copied into the IL for those other assemblies. Whether that gets interned cross-assembly or not depends on a CLR setting IIRC.

However, if you're worried about whether you'll get a new string *or* a new string variable for each instance of `MyClass`, you don't need to worry - `const` implies `static`.

In short, unless you've got huge, *huge* wads of constants (or enormous string constants) it's not going to cause you an issue.

Comment: I think this wikipedia page for [Oxymoron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxymoron) should point back here... (Jon using IIRC ...it's like Chuck Norris wondering if he can get out of bed. Look [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9182/237379) for other Jon facts ... :)

Comment: Hey @Jon Skeet , - "const implies static. " means  conatant is by default static and single copy of constant variable will be generated for different  all objects. ?

Comment: @vimalraturi: It means there's a single field regardless of the number of instances, even if there are none of them.

Comment: Saying it won't cause an issue unless you have huge numbers of constants is incorrect. As a constant is replaced at compile time, it should never have an issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23529592/how-are-c-sharp-const-members-allocated-in-memory

Comment: @CBFT: The fact that it's replaced at compile time *is the point*. You end up with a copy of the constant in every assembly that references that constant. As I say in the answer, whether those separate copies (one per assembly) are then interned is a more complicated matter.

Comment: Saying it acts the same as the literal "AConstant" would be more accurate than a static variable. A static variable cannot be garbage collected. I looked at your answer and thought I should avoid const given how large our application is.

Comment: @CBFT: Given that I specifically say "unless you've got huge, *huge* wads of constants it's not going to cause you an issue" I think that's an overreaction. Note that I didn't say it acts the same as a static variable - I said that `const` implies `static`, which it does - and the context of the rest of the sentence was in comparison with an instance variable. (Not that constants can be garbage collected either, as far as I'm aware.)

Comment: @CBFT: Of course, if you *really* think this 12-year-old question should be answered differently, there's nothing to stop you from adding your own answer. I'm content with the one I've written.

Comment: I and many users are using these answers to write code currently. That is why having misleading answers to old questions is still a problem. There are very good answers already here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23529592/how-are-c-sharp-const-members-allocated-in-memory

Comment: @CBFT: Again, I don't believe this is misleading. This is my last comment here - I don't think it's productive to discuss this any further.